# PHP automated test runner with notifications for OS X

Tags: php, ruby, automated-tests

I had something similar for Ruby once. It would auto-detect changes in the code, re-run the tests and show a green/red notification in Growl.

Does something like this exist for PHP? Can I maybe bend some of the Ruby tools to execute PHPUnit tests?

Thx,
MrB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [watchr](http://github.com/mynyml/watchr) (a rubygem). It supports growl and will watch the file system for changes. Writing a custom watchr script should be straight forward or you could try the [watchr-phpunit](https://github.com/proofek/watchr-phpunit) project on GitHub.

Also, here's a blog post about setting up [watchr, PHPUnit and Growl](http://criticallog.thornet.net/2011/03/08/autotesting-with-watchr-growl-and-phpunit/).

Comment: Works perfectly, awesome. Thank you very much. (I wrote a watchr script).

Comment: I've posted my watchr.rb on github: https://github.com/bleicke/watchr-phpunit-yii-config